# $\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} e^{2x^2} dx\geq\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi }e^{2x^2} \sin(kx)\,dx)^2$

Tags: calculus

How to prove the following inequality?

> $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} e^{2x^2} \mathrm dx\geq\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} e^{2x^2} \sin (kx)\, \mathrm dx\right)^2$$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: sorry i was edited now

Comment: This looks a bit like Bessel's inequality (not precisely that, though). Are you familiar with it?

Comment: sorry i don't have idea

Comment: What's your background?

Comment: bacahlor degree

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a silly problem because $e^{2x^2}$ is even on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $\sin(kx)$ is odd, making the right-hand-side equal to 0. In general, take a look at [Parseval's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity), which immediately asserts the inequality.